# Check whether CGPoint is in many CGRect for thousands times per second

Tags: ios, drawrect

I am doing drawing app. Tracking user finger, I got CGPoint and I need to check whether that CGPoint is in my multiple CGRect. Checking is okay. My code is like this.

```
[self.inputOptionRects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSValue *rectValue, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    CGRect keyRect = [rectValue CGRectValue];
    CGRect infiniteKeyRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(keyRect), 0, CGRectGetWidth(keyRect), NSIntegerMax);
    infiniteKeyRect = CGRectInset(infiniteKeyRect, -3, 0);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(infiniteKeyRect, location)) {
        selectedInputIndex = idx;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

The only problem is that when user finger move, it generate many many CGPoint (I think so) and app need to process so many times. As a result, my memory usage goes up terribly and app crash. Is there a better way to handle my case?

## Edit

Or is there a way to get notified event when cgpoint is changed and goes inside one of the cgrect ? If so, I won't need to check multiple times.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back, having to do with finding if a touch point was inside certain CGRect, heres a link maybe it'll help depending on your use case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540133/how-to-detect-a-touch-in-a-subview-that-was-dragged-there-or-fastest-way-to-get

Comment: First thing I would do is cache the previous CGRect because the finger may not have moved at all. That way, you only have to check against one CGRect until the finger actually moves.

Comment: Why do all this with a block API, just loop over the objects in the array directly with a for loop?